# How to change UIAlertView text color?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uialertview

I'm currently using http://kwigbo.com/post/318396305/iphone-sdk-custom-uialertview-background-color for my custom UIAlertView. Everything is working fine but I'm trying to change the title and message text colors and I would like to change the button color. Is there any way to do this? I've tried using:

```
UILabel *theTitle = [AlertView valueForKey:@"_titleLabel"];
    [theTitle setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

but I can't get it to work. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to see if setTextColor is depricated.

I thought it was

```
theTitle.text.color = [UIColor redColor];
```

or you could use

```
[theTitle.text setColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Not totally sure on the second one, the first example should do the trick though.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to include `UIAlertViewDelegate` in your `.h` file and override this method in your `.m` file.

```
-(void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView{
    UILabel *theTitle = [alertView valueForKey:@"_titleLabel"];
    theTitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Copperplate" size:18];
    [theTitle setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    UILabel *theBody = [alertView valueForKey:@"_bodyTextLabel"];
    theBody.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Copperplate" size:15];
    [theBody setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
}
```

Comment: +1, but in ios 5.1 the _bodyTextLabel's settings doesn't work for me, maybe because I have a longer text

Comment: This is a bad solution and not future proof as it uses private variables (in a roundabout way)

Answer (score 0):

By default functionality, you could not change alert view title and message but with the help of accessory view, you can achieve this functionality. 
Try below method :

```
-(void)customAlertTitle:(NSString*)title message:(NSString*)message{
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"NO" otherButtonTitles:@"YES", nil];
UIView *subView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 80)];

UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 270, 50)];
titleLabel.text = title;
titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];
titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

[subView addSubview:titleLabel];

UILabel *messageLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 30, 270, 50)];
messageLabel.text = message;
messageLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];
messageLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
messageLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
messageLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

[subView addSubview:messageLabel];

[alertView setValue:subView forKey:@"accessoryView"];
[alertView show];
}
```

The above code is working perfectly on latest XCode 8.3.1. Kindly comment if facing any problem.