# Setting text and button color for Alert component in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

It might not be a great idea to set text color in Alert but I would love to know if the possibility is there.

How to set text and button text color for the Alert component in SwiftUI. Tried the code below but the color set seems to be ignored by the library.

```
.alert(isPresented: $showingTrackingAlert) {
    Alert(
        title: Text("TITLE").foregroundColor(.red),
        message: Text("MESSAGE TEXT").foregroundColor(.red),
        primaryButton: .destructive(Text("DELETE").foregroundColor(.red)),
        secondaryButton: .cancel(Text("CANCEL").foregroundColor(.red))
    )
}
```

**REFERECE**

[How to change UIAlertView text color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755313/how-to-change-uialertview-text-color)

Comment: SwiftUI does not support such feature for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main goal was to set the cancel button text so a workaround we ended up with is to set a global tint color inside

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo _: UISceneSession, options _: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {}
```

with the following code

```
UIView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIAlertController.self]).tintColor = UIColor(named: "secondaryColorDefinedInAssets")
```